# Regex: matching "S**E**", where * is a single integer value?

Tags: regex

I've read various resources and can't find anything which can easily explain how to match this format of string.

Something similar to this below?

```
/S[0-15][0-15]E[0-24]/
```

Comment: So `S1515E12` should really be a match but `S160E12` should not?

Answer (score 4):

Regex `[]` matches all *single* characters in the brackets. You need to split it into multiple part expressions.

Try this:

```
/S(0?[0-9]|1[0-5])E([01]?[0-9]|2[0-4])/
```

About the use of the hyphen, pleas read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: This matches some cases, but not others, e.g S01E05 is not matched (according to http://pythex.org/). Is this because of the use of '|'?

Comment: No, I did not think about the starting "0". Now it should work.

Comment: @Masutatsu Sorry, if the double `[0-15]` above is not a typo, you have to use
`/S(0?[0-9]|1[0-5]){2}E([01]?[0-9]|2[0-4])/`

Comment: Great, thank-you so much! Do I need to add anything to allow any string either side (e.g. so that it would match TV.SHOW.S01E06.TV.SHOW)?

Comment: If you want just to match it should be ok (or try to append and prepend `.*`, it depends on the function you are using). If you want to replace some text with other, you should probably adjust the capturing gorups.